# C# User Input Random numbers

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, random, input

I need help writing a code that as the user to input 10 numbers between 50 and 150 without repeating the same numbers. This will be a looping program. Here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IP3_Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int total = 0;
            string inValue;
            int [] number = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number{0}: ", i + 1);
                inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inValue);
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks okay so far.  What do you need help with?

Comment: you want to look at [if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: You need to have a specific problem so we can help you, not just ask for perfectly running code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
while (numbers.Count != 10)
{
    // get number from user

    if (numbers.Contains(newNumber) || newNumber < 50 || newNumber > 150)
    {
        // reject the number
        // you'd probably want to display a message here
        // alerting the user another input in needed
    }
    else
    {
        numbers.Add(newNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: needs to be between `50` and `150`

Comment: @Default 10 numbers between 50 and 150

Comment: exactly. so how does your code validate `49`?

Comment: almost, flip the conditionals - don't reject if it's between 50 and 150.

Comment: opps, thanks... that always gets me...